# How to establish second strike capabilities for nuclear deterrence

Tags: freeciv

I control a small but prosperous coastal state of three cities, and I fear that I may soon be wiped out by one of the larger hostile states. I am able to produce nuclear missiles to deter invasions by massed enemy units, but I have no SDI Defense to intercept enemy missiles. What I now need is to deter nuclear attacks by implementing a policy of mutually assured destruction (MAD) through [second-strike capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_strike).

I thought about sending nuclear-armed submarines on global patrols, and placing nuclear missiles in my allies' cities and air bases where they are able to hit enemy targets. But on second thought, second-strike capability might not be possible in Freeciv. If a nuclear-armed enemy were to conduct a first strike to nuke all three of my cities and conquer them within a single turn, all my nuclear missiles and submarines would immediately disappear, making a second strike impossible. Is this really the case? If so, how do I configure Freeciv so that I would be able to use second-strike capabilities as a nuclear deterrent?

Comment: I would be surprised if this were possible, but I'm also curious if it were, or if someone made a mod to include this. It's a very specific situation relating to the late stages of the game though.

Comment: Btw, [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357164/will-freeciv-ai-ever-use-nuclear-weapons) suggests the AI's use of nukes is rare, and possibly only at the highest difficulty levels, due to the possibility of triggering a nuclear winter. This doesn't mean your nuclear deterrent may or may not work, just that they're unlikely to commit to a first (nuclear) strike.

Comment: Also, a funny anecdote about [Nuclear Gandhi](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/30-years-civ-all-the-little-things-you-didnt-know.673477/) from the original Civ :)